# How to search multiple columns in SQLite db?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I got a problem when trying to search in multiple columns of a SQLite db.
Here ist my current code

```
String whereClause;
    if (!suchwort.contains("%")){  // Abfrage mit Wildcard?
        whereClause = WoerterbuchContract.WoerterbuchEintraege.COLUMN_NAME_WORT_DEUTSCH
                        + " = '"+suchwort+"'" ;}


    else {
        whereClause = WoerterbuchContract.WoerterbuchEintraege.COLUMN_NAME_WORT_DEUTSCH
                        +" like '"+suchwort+"'";}


    Cursor ergCursor = db.query(
            WoerterbuchContract.WoerterbuchEintraege.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            whereClause,                              // WHERE clause
            null,                                     // no values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
            sortOrder                                 // The sort order
    );
```

I tried adding columns to my whereClause, but i allways get compiler errors.

Comment: Just remove ; at the end.

Comment: `... WHERE This='Something' AND That='Something Else'` or use placeholders: `... WHERE This=? AND That=?` and use the syntax which passes the parameters in a string array.